# ms access error 3078 cannot find table or query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Thanks in advance everyone, Im using **vba** and **MS Access 2016** to work on a restaurant's db.
I need to open a table to get a record which is a table name that I then need to open, its kinda messy but I thought I had it until I started getting the **3078** error. (Btw I just started using access for this project so it could be a simple syntax error I don't see)

The db im working on was made in a half assed way unfortunately so it isn't quietly consistent or well formated and it is half in spanish half in english however **I'm sure the table name is correct and exists**. If I put the query in access instead of vba and with the name instead of a variable it works just fine. Here's the code.

```
Sub QRventas()
    Dim ventas As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qrv As String

    'Query daily sales
    qrv = (SELECT menus.id, menus.descripcion, Sum(Nz(ComandasD.cantidad)) AS Total FROM ~~long and ugly but working query)

    Set ventas = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qrv)
    Dim receta As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qrr As String

    Do While Not ventas.EOF

        'QR recipes
        ventas.MoveNext

        qrr = "SELECT ID, Ingredientes, Cantidad FROM [" & ventas(1) & "] GROUP BY ID, Ingredientes, Cantidad;" '<- Error Here

        Set receta = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qrr)  '<- Complains here 3078
        Do While Not receta.EOF
            'Updating Storage

             CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Almacen " _
                                & "SET Cantidad_almacenada = Cantidad_almacenada - (cantidad * Total) " _
                                & "WHERE ID = " & receta(1) & ";"
            receta.MoveNext
        Loop

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a message box to show what ventas(1) contains before the assignment to qrr ?  If that appears to be ok, then also do a message box after the qrr assignment to ensure that the query syntax appears to be correct.

Comment: ...alternatively, if you know how to use the debugger, set a break point on ventas.MoveNext and inspect the variables from that interface as you step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

possibly 'Fields' is missing:

`qrr = "SELECT ID, Ingredientes, Cantidad FROM [" & ventas.Fields(1) & "]...`

Comment: Tried it but I got the same result, I had tried debugging ventas(1) before to see what it returned and the value was the same

Answer (score 1):

If Access complains that the table isn't there, it isn't.

Or, specifically use the *Value* property of the field.

So insert a debug line and study which table name it was supposed to find:

```
    'QR recipes
    ventas.MoveNext
    Debug.Print "[" & ventas(1) & "]"

    qrr = "SELECT ID, Ingredientes, Cantidad FROM [" & ventas(1).Value & "] GROUP BY ID, Ingredientes, Cantidad;" '<- Error Here
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers that people posted here but had no luck with them, then I did a "Compact and Repair" and the issue went away...
Thanks everyone again.